# Install service with delphi?

Tags: delphi, service

I want a small executable to install my service with the usual

```
path\servicename /install
```

I've tried running a simple shellexecute in a program with elevated rights,

```
ShellExecute(0, nil, 'cmd.exe','/C servicepath\servicename.exe /install', nil, SW_HIDE);
```

but the service doesn't install. I am not exactly a wiz with ShellEx so I suspect I have gotten it wrong; kindly show me the errors of my ways and possibly supply the correct shellexecute line

Comment: why passing via cmd? execute your service directly...

Comment: `ShellExecute(0, nil, 'servicepath\servicename.exe','/install', nil, SW_HIDE);`

Comment: @J... that worked for me, thanks :)

Comment: ShellExecute is a function to run commands in the shell - it's to do things that you would do manually in the console.  If you were in a console you wouldn't install a service by starting with `C:>cmd.exe ...` and launching another console, passing the command as a parameter.  Parameter 3 is the application you want to run, parameter 4 are the arguments.  For what it's worth, although circuitous, the command you have in your question would work if you added double-quotes around the command `'/C "servicepath\servicename.exe /install"'`

Comment: ShellExecute is the wrong function. Use CreateProcess. Unless you need the runas verb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper way to install a service from code is to call the Service Control Manager (SCM) API. The /install parameter supplied by Delphi service does a "standard" call to the SCM that usually is not the best one for most services. Today, very few services, for example, should run with LocalSystem privileges because it's too powerful.

Comment: A Delphi service installs itself using whatever user account is configured in the `TService.ServiceStartName` property, where LocalSystem is the default when no account is specified. That is Microsoft's default, not Delphi's. It is the service author's responsibility to configure the service to run with necessary privilege levels.

Comment: @Remy The service installer rather than the author has to do that. It requires creating a new user, or choosing an existing one. The service author cannot do that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The default Delphi implementation lets you "hardcode" the value of the `ServiceStartName` property in the .dfm. (This could also be a "[well-known](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686005%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)" account name like `'NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService'`, `'NT AUTHORITY\LocalService'`, `'.\LocalSystem'`.). The service author can write code to process additional command line parameters to let the installer override this hardcoded value.

Comment: @Lebeau: for several reason, I don't like services that installs themselves and have settings built-in. It takes little to change them in the dfm, or read the user account password stored there .) I would remove the whole autoinstall feature from TService, now that SC.EXE could easily be used from the command line to manage services.
I agree with Heffernan that is the installer responsibility to perform service installation and removal, Windows defaults are no longer safe enough, and needs to be changed whenever possible.